# How to check whether there is a record satisfying some condition in a sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have the following code

```
public int getIngCount(String id,String ingrediant) {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS2 + " WHERE id = "+id+ " AND ingrediant = "+ingrediant;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);


        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();

    }
```

But when there is no records satisfying the condition, it causing an exception (no such column) instead of returning 0.

pls help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the stacktrace, please.

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: Showing sqlite exception : no such column @Fildor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ingrediant` should be treated as a string literal and not as an identifier such as a column name. In SQL you use single quotes for string literals. It's a better idea to use `?` placeholders for binding literal values, though:

```
String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS2 + " WHERE id = "+id+ " AND ingrediant = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, new String[] { ingrediant });
```

Also, don't call any cursor methods after closing it.

Comment: Its the call after closing it that causes the exception.  But yes, NEVER use concatenation for parameters, ALWAYS use bind variables or you'll have SQL Injection security holes.